# Django 2.1 model managers missing in action

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have defined a recursive model and a custom manager or two to contain some of the interesting tree exploring methods.  I've recently updated to Django 2.1, Python 3.6.

```
# models.py
class ParentManager(models.Manager):

def get_queryset(self, pk=None):
    qs = super().get_queryset()

    def parent(parent_list):
        """
        given a brainstorm object that responds to something
        (mainly if user clicks a header)
        it returns the upstream brainstorm object it responds to
        """
        if parent_list[0].responds_to:
            parent_list.insert(0, qs.get(pk=parent_list[0].responds_to.pk))
            parent(parent_list)
        return parent_list

    if pk:
        parent_list = [qs.get(pk=pk), ]
        parent(parent_list)
        pk_list = [item.pk for item in parent_list]
        return qs.filter(pk__in=pk_list)
    else:
        return qs

class Demand(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='child', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    counterpart = models.ForeignKey('Supply', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    demands = models.Manager()
    parents = ParentManager()
    children = ChildManager()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        _qs, pk_list = Demand.parents.get_queryset(pk=self.pk)
        return 'demand/' + "-".join(pk_list)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Trying to get a simple ListView of the two test 'Demands' I've created in the admin, I am getting the error 'Demand has no attribute 'demands.' It was the same with 'objects' and I get the same error with my custom objects.

```
# views.py
class DemandList(ListView):
    """Django generic listview of available Demands within a project"""
    template_name = 'forcedesign/ListView.html'
    model = Demand
    context_object_name = 'demand_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        print("Dir of Demand class:", dir(Demand))
        return Demand.demands.all()
```

This is the stacktrace:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/fd/demand/
>
> Django Version: 2.1 Python Version: 3.6.0 Installed Applications:
>   ['polls.apps.PollsConfig',  'forcedesign.apps.ForcedesignConfig', 
>   'django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'import_export'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in view
>     68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py"
>   in dispatch
>     88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py"
>   in get
>     142.         self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
>
> File
>   "H:\Workspace\Django_Code\Acejet_development\forcedesign\views.py" in
>   get_queryset
>     24.         return Demand.demands.all()
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at /fd/demand/ Exception Value: type
>   object 'Demand' has no attribute 'demands'

If I print dir(Demand), I get:

> Dir of Demand class: ['**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**init_subclass**', '**le**', '**lt**', '**module**',
>   '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_allowed_methods', 'as_view', 'dispatch', 'get', 'http_method_names', 'http_method_not_
>   allowed', 'options', 'post', 'template']

So that indicates to me that in Views.py, the Demand that is imported from models is actually a class-based view class.  I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0):

Dammit, something about posting here clears my head.  The problem is that in my Views.py below my list view I had stupidly overloaded Demand as a View sub-class. So this all makes perfect sense.